# Inequality for smooth convex function defined in non Euclidean norm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\mathcal{X} $ be a closed, convex and bounded set. Consider a convex function $f : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is  differentiable with $L$ Lipschitz smooth gradient w.r.t a norm $\| \cdot \|$ that is not necessarily the Euclidean norm. Let $\| \cdot \|_*$ be the dual norm of $\|\cdot \|$, i.e., $\|x\|_* = \max \{ \langle x, u \rangle \mid \|u \| = 1\}$. For every $x, y \in \mathcal{X}$, does the following inequality hold?

$$ f(x) - f(y) - \langle \nabla f(y), x - y \rangle \ge \frac{1}{2 L} \| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \|^2_* . $$

The above is true when $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_*$ are both the Euclidean norm which can be found in many textbooks, however, I can't find any statement regarding the non-Euclidean case. The proof used for the Euclidean case doesn't seem to apply to the more general case.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{X}$? Is it convex? Is it closed? Is it bounded?

Comment: Yes, it is closed, convex, and bounded.

Comment: What inner product are you using?

Comment: An inner product here is a function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : \mathcal{X}^* \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the definitions of inner product, i.e., symmetry, linearity, and positive-definiteness.

Comment: So you want the inequality to hold for every inner product?  I don't believe that will work even in the 2-norm case.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I mean the standard set up like the one found in this paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.7816&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: @BrianBorchers You are right, the case where the inequality has been shown to work is when the norm is 2-norm, and it is self-dual, which means the inner product has to be the dot product in that case. I have made an edit to my question accordingly.

Comment: See the notation section of Nesterov's paper on pages 128-129 and the definition of Lipschitz continuity of the gradient with respect to the norm and its dual on page 132.  You're asking for a proof of (3.1) in this paper, right?  It would help if you provided this context in your question.

Comment: I think the inequality $x^{T}z \leq \| x \| \| z \|^{*}$ will be enough to make the proof for the 2-norm go through.

Comment: @BrianBorchers No, I am not asking for proof of (3.1) in Nesterov's paper. In Theorem 3 of this course note http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/jliu/CSC-576/class-note-6.pdf, there are 4 equivalent definitions of Lipschitz smoothness in the Euclidean norm case when the inner product is the dot product. Everything still holds if we go to the general case except the case of (1) => (2), which is my question.

Comment: What is there in the proof of (1) -> (2) in your lecture notes that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Firstly, it defines an intermediate variable $z = y - \frac{1}{L} \nabla \phi(y)$, but in the general case, $y \in \mathcal{X}$ and $\nabla \phi(y) \in \mathcal{X}^*$, hence the subtraction between the two is not well defined. Secondly, even if $z$ can be defined that way, later it would require $ \langle \nabla \phi(y), \nabla \phi(y) \rangle = \| \nabla \phi(y) \|_*^2$, which is not true unless the norm is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Have you tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I tried but cannot find any counterexample. Now I think this is true. The LHS is the Bregman divergence, and $D_f(x, y) = D_{f^*}(\nabla f(y), \nabla f(x)) \ge \frac{1}{2L} \| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \|^2_*, $ where $f^*$ is the convex conjugate of $f$. The first equality is due to the duality property of $D_f(\cdot)$, and the second inequality is due to Theorem 1 of http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~shai/papers/KakadeShalevTewari09.pdf, which states that $f$ is $L$-strongly smooth in $\|\cdot\|$ iff $f^*$ is $\frac{1}{L}$-strongly convex in $\|\cdot\|_*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I think the answer is yes. Since LHS is the Bregman divergence of $f$, let $f^*$ be the convex conjugate of $f$, we have 
$$ D_f(x,y) = D_f^*(\nabla f(y), \nabla f(x)) \ge \frac{1}{2L} \| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \|_*^2, $$
where the first equality is due to the duality property of Bregman divergence (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence), and the second inequality is due to the fact that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz smooth if and only if $f^*$ is $\frac{1}{L}$-strongly convex. (see Theorem 1 of http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~shai/papers/KakadeShalevTewari09.pdf).